# spark SQL select query does not obtain date value, getting null instead

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have an external Hive table having a birth_date column defined as date datatype. Data is stored in HDFS as text file, and that column contains value "1980-12-12 00:00:00" (checked by running hdfs dfs -cat on the data)
Using PySpark utilizing Hive Metastore to perform spark.sql("select birth_date from table").show() resulted on null values for all rows.
However, reading the data using spark.read.format("csv").load("//hdfs/path") shows the value as 1980-12-12 (printSchema() shows that the column type is date).

Is there any way the date column can be parsed to obtain the value when using Spark SQL Query? Possibly any additional configs to be applied for the specific Spark Session?
I've looked around and tried cast, date_format, and similar approach but it keeps giving null value for that date column.

Comment: @ Gin Are you using Databricks community edition or Azure databricks?

Comment: either you change the type to timestamp or you change your data to a real date format.

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula It's an on premise hadoop cluster running HDFS 3.3.1, Hive 3.1.2, Spark 3.0.2. Can you elaborate what may be the relation between this issue and the platform?

Comment: @Steven got it, I reckon that would be the most ideal thing to do. but still I'm stuck on why does it work when reading the hdfs or using Tez engine via Dbeaver, but not with spark sql. Would appreciate any probable workaround.